# Using Chinese Remainder Theorem when the moduli are not mutually coprime.

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am unable to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem when the modulus is not coprime. I want to solve the following:

$$ x \equiv 5 \text{ (mod 6)}\\ x \equiv 7\text{ (mod 15)} $$
I tried breaking the system as:

$$ x\equiv5\text{ (mod 2)}\\  x\equiv5\text{ (mod 3)}\\ x\equiv7\text{ (mod 3)}\\x\equiv7\text{ (mod 5)}
$$
and using the values of $x \text{ (mod 3)}$, I got a contradiction, but clearly $x =22$ is a solution. Can you please help me find where I have gone wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is good; see my answer below

Comment: So, I guess this system does not have any solution in integers. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=22$ is not a solution, since $22\not\equiv5\pmod6$.